# Keyboard layout statistics and javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a variety of input methods on my site, and I've seen that some people have compiled libraries of keyboard layouts, but I need to know which keyboard layouts are the most common across languages and regions in order to give them an experience that is not infuriatingly unfamiliar.

There are many permutations of keyboard layouts for each language, so I'm not talking about just QWERTY vs DVORAK

Usually the OS takes care of this, and we let the chips fall where they may... but I need to understand this. For example, I've learned that in france and belgium, the AZERTY layout is common. And I'm not even getting into logographic languages like chinese, korean, etc. which not have quasi-phonetic alphabets like the rest of the world. They of course have a few thousand characters to contend with.

Despite my googling, I cannot find a centralized store of information about layouts. Does anyone know where I can find keyboard layout statistics?